# Sort ListA of TSV strings given another ListB that contains partial string from ListA

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting

I have 2 lists: `ListA` that contains strings delimited by tabs and `ListB` that contains strings that partially match the strings in `ListA`. I would like to order the strings in `ListA` in the same order found in `ListB` by having the partial strings of `ListB` match the strings in `ListA`.

What I tried is to loop on `ListA`, split each line by `\t`, split the 5th column by `_` and append the string to a temporary `ListC`. Then, I ordered `ListC` but I still don't know how I can order the actual `ListA` given `ListC`.

```
ListA = ['rs141130360\tchr1:16495\tC\t653635\tNC_024540.1\tTranscript\tintron_variant,non_coding_transcript_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs3210724\tG\tMODIFIER\t-\t-1\t-\tSNV\tWASH7P\tEntrezGene\tHGNC:38034\ttranscribed_pseudogene\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tRefSeq\tG\tG\tOK\t-\t-\t-\t-\t8/10\t-\t-\tNR_024540.1:n.1080+112C>G\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n',
         'rs141130360\tchr1:16495\tC\t100287102\tNR_046018.2\tTranscript\tdownstream_gene_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs3210724\tG\tMODIFIER\t2086\t1\t-\tSNV\tDDX11L1\tEntrezGene\tHGNC:37102\ttranscribed_pseudogene\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tRefSeq\tG\tG\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n',
         'rs141130360\tchr1:16495\tC\t102466751\tNG_106918.1\tTranscript\tdownstream_gene_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs3210724\tG\tMODIFIER\t874\t-1\t-\tSNV\tMIR6859-1\tEntrezGene\tHGNC:50039\tmiRNA\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tRefSeq\tG\tG\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n']

ListB = ["NC", "NG", "NM", "NP", "NR", "XM", "XP", "XR", "WP"]
ListC = []


for i in ListA:
    i_split = i.split("\t")[4].split("_")[0]
    ListC.append(i_split)
ListC = sorted(ListC, key=lambda x: ListB.index(x))
print(ListC)
```

will print:

```
['NC', 'NG', 'NR']
```

My expected results is the following:

```
['rs141130360\tchr1:16495\tC\t653635\tNC_024540.1\tTranscript\tintron_variant,non_coding_transcript_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs3210724\tG\tMODIFIER\t-\t-1\t-\tSNV\tWASH7P\tEntrezGene\tHGNC:38034\ttranscribed_pseudogene\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tRefSeq\tG\tG\tOK\t-\t-\t-\t-\t8/10\t-\t-\tNR_024540.1:n.1080+112C>G\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n',
'rs141130360\tchr1:16495\tC\t102466751\tNG_106918.1\tTranscript\tdownstream_gene_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs3210724\tG\tMODIFIER\t874\t-1\t-\tSNV\tMIR6859-1\tEntrezGene\tHGNC:50039\tmiRNA\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tRefSeq\tG\tG\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n', 
'rs141130360\tchr1:16495\tC\t100287102\tNR_046018.2\tTranscript\tdownstream_gene_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs3210724\tG\tMODIFIER\t2086\t1\t-\tSNV\tDDX11L1\tEntrezGene\tHGNC:37102\ttranscribed_pseudogene\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tRefSeq\tG\tG\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would instead convert `ListB` to a `[value, index]` dictionary, then create a function that extracts the value from the string and looks it up in the dict.  That will be our `key` function for `sorted`.

```
d = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(ListB)}

def get_index(s):
    by_tabs = s.split('\t')
    by_underscore = by_tabs[4].split('_')
    return d[by_underscore[0]]

listC = sorted(ListA, key=get_index)
```

Comment: Thank you Patrick Haugh ! It works nicely ! it been since this morning I've been trying to storm my mind for that ... I didn't think it would be so simple...