# Improving code sort ListA of TSV strings given another ListB that contains partial string from ListA and return the first order for each pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

Following my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54693487/sort-lista-of-tsv-strings-given-another-listb-that-contains-partial-string-from), I face another challenge.

I have the following new `listA`

```
listA = ['rs141130360\tchr1:16495\tC\t653635\tNC_024540.1\tTranscript\tintron_variant,non_coding_transcript_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs3210724\tG\tMODIFIER\t-\t-1\t-\tSNV\tWASH7P\tEntrezGene\tHGNC:38034\ttranscribed_pseudogene\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tRefSeq\tG\tG\tOK\t-\t-\t-\t-\t8/10\t-\t-\tNR_024540.1:n.1080+112C>G\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n',
         'rs141130360\tchr1:16495\tC\t100287102\tNR_046018.2\tTranscript\tframeshift_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs3210724\tG\tMODIFIER\t2086\t1\t-\tSNV\tDDX11L1\tEntrezGene\tHGNC:37102\ttranscribed_pseudogene\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tRefSeq\tG\tG\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n',
         'rs141130360\tchr1:16495\tC\t102466751\tNG_106918.1\tTranscript\tdownstream_gene_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs3210724\tG\tMODIFIER\t874\t-1\t-\tSNV\tMIR6859-1\tEntrezGene\tHGNC:50039\tmiRNA\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tRefSeq\tG\tG\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n',
         'rs141130360\tchr1:16495\tC\t102466751\tNG_106918.1\tTranscript\tdownstream_gene_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs3210724\tG\tMODIFIER\t874\t-1\t-\tSNV\tMIR6859-1\tEntrezGene\tHGNC:50039\tmiRNA\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tRefSeq\tG\tG\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n',
         'rs62636367\tchr1:16719\tA\t653635\tNR_024540.1\tTranscript\tnon_coding_transcript_exon_variant\t968\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs62636367\tT\tMODIFIER\t-\t-1\t-\tSNV\tWASH7P\tEntrezGene\tHGNC:38034\ttranscribed_pseudogene\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tRefSeq\tT\tT\tOK\t-\t-\t-\t8/11\t-\t-\t-\tNR_024540.1:n.968A>T\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n',
         'rs62636367\tchr1:16719\tA\t100287102\tNR_046018.2\tTranscript\tdownstream_gene_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs62636367\tT\tMODIFIER\t2310\t1\t-\tSNV\tDDX11L1\tEntrezGene\tHGNC:37102\ttranscribed_pseudogene\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tRefSeq\tT\tT\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n',
         'rs62636367\tchr1:16719\tA\t102466751\tNC_106918.1\tTranscript\tframeshift_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs62636367\tT\tMODIFIER\t650\t-1\t-\tSNV\tMIR6859-1\tEntrezGene\tHGNC:50039\tmiRNA\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tRefSeq\tT\tT\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n']
```

and the same `listB` and an empty `listC`

```
ListB = ["NC", "NG", "NM", "NP", "NR", "XM", "XP", "XR", "WP"]
listC = []
```

using the following code, I can reorder `listA` according to `listB` by matching the string in `listB` to the 5th column of `listA`:

```
d = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(listB)}

def get_index(s):
    by_tabs = s.split('\t')
    by_underscore = by_tabs[4].split('_')
    return d[by_underscore[0]]

listC = sorted(listA, key=get_index)
```

and `listC` will output:

```
print(listC)
['rs141130360\tchr1:16495\tC\t653635\tNC_024540.1\tTranscript\tintron_variant,non_coding_transcript_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs3210724\tG\tMODIFIER\t-\t-1\t-\tSNV\tWASH7P\tEntrezGene\tHGNC:38034\ttranscribed_pseudogene\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tRefSeq\tG\tG\tOK\t-\t-\t-\t-\t8/10\t-\t-\tNR_024540.1:n.1080+112C>G\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n', 
'rs62636367\tchr1:16719\tA\t102466751\tNC_106918.1\tTranscript\tframeshift_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs62636367\tT\tMODIFIER\t650\t-1\t-\tSNV\tMIR6859-1\tEntrezGene\tHGNC:50039\tmiRNA\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tRefSeq\tT\tT\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n', 
'rs141130360\tchr1:16495\tC\t102466751\tNG_106918.1\tTranscript\tdownstream_gene_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs3210724\tG\tMODIFIER\t874\t-1\t-\tSNV\tMIR6859-1\tEntrezGene\tHGNC:50039\tmiRNA\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tRefSeq\tG\tG\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n',
'rs141130360\tchr1:16495\tC\t102466751\tNG_106918.1\tTranscript\tdownstream_gene_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs3210724\tG\tMODIFIER\t874\t-1\t-\tSNV\tMIR6859-1\tEntrezGene\tHGNC:50039\tmiRNA\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tRefSeq\tG\tG\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n',
'rs141130360\tchr1:16495\tC\t100287102\tNR_046018.2\tTranscript\tframeshift_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs3210724\tG\tMODIFIER\t2086\t1\t-\tSNV\tDDX11L1\tEntrezGene\tHGNC:37102\ttranscribed_pseudogene\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tRefSeq\tG\tG\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n',
'rs62636367\tchr1:16719\tA\t653635\tNR_024540.1\tTranscript\tnon_coding_transcript_exon_variant\t968\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs62636367\tT\tMODIFIER\t-\t-1\t-\tSNV\tWASH7P\tEntrezGene\tHGNC:38034\ttranscribed_pseudogene\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tRefSeq\tT\tT\tOK\t-\t-\t-\t8/11\t-\t-\t-\tNR_024540.1:n.968A>T\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n',
'rs62636367\tchr1:16719\tA\t100287102\tNR_046018.2\tTranscript\tdownstream_gene_variant\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\trs62636367\tT\tMODIFIER\t2310\t1\t-\tSNV\tDDX11L1\tEntrezGene\tHGNC:37102\ttranscribed_pseudogene\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\tRefSeq\tT\tT\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n']
```

I want to return the first element from `listC` that is sorted according to `listB` for each `key` from the `dictionary`. My attempt to obtain the desired output in a fast way is the following: I have an additional dictionary which contains all the keys that comes from the first TSV column (`dictionary = { 'rs141130360': 'value', 'rs62636367': 'value', etc...}`

```
for i in list(dictionary.keys()):
    print(next((x for x in listC if i in x), ""))
```

will correctly print:

```
rs141130360 chr1:16495  C   653635  NC_024540.1 Transcript  intron_variant,non_coding_transcript_variant    -   -   -   -   -   rs3210724   G   MODIFIER    -   -1  -   SNV WASH7P  EntrezGene  HGNC:38034  transcribed_pseudogene  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   RefSeq  G   G   OK  -   -   -   -   8/10    -   -   NR_024540.1:n.1080+112C>G   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
rs62636367  chr1:16719  A   102466751   NC_106918.1 Transcript  frameshift_variant  -   -   -   -   -   rs62636367  T   MODIFIER    650 -1  -   SNV MIR6859-1   EntrezGene  HGNC:50039  miRNA   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   RefSeq  T   T   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
```

However, the problem is that my real `listA` contains `532493` elements. Iterating over this huge list takes a lot of time.

I desire to obtain the same output above but in less possible run time (it is currently running and still haven't finished after `30 mins`. If I am guessing correctly, something should be done to the function `get_index(s)` but I am not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: `What I wish to obtain is only the first order of listC` what does that mean

Comment: it means I want to return the first element from `listC` that is sorted according to `listB` for each `key` from the `dictionary`.

Comment: isn't it already doing that or you mean disregard duplicates?

Comment: @aws_apprentice yes it is doing what it needs but it's very slow. I am looking for a way to improve the code to run faster, maybe it should be done on a previous step ? I mean the `listA` is created by iterating on the list of `value` of the `dictionary` in the first place. Maybe a way to do it is by sorting the list of the dictionary itself...